# Count rows that have same value in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F      
------------------
1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  1  1  1  1
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1
```

How can I get the number of rows that have value `1` in every column?
In this case, **2** rows have `1` in every field.

I know one way, for example if we only take columns `A` and `B`:

```
count = df2.query("A == 1 & B == 1").shape[0]
```

But I have to put the name of every column, is there a more fancy approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try : ``df.loc[df.eq(1).all(1)]``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(df == 1).all(axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 3):

For the large data frame and multiple row , you may always want to try with `any` , since when it detect the first item , it will yield the result

```
sum(~df.ne(1).any(1))
2
```

Comment: I like the insight into using any for "short circuit" logic efficiencies.